# How to access java properties file

Tags: java, class, properties, getproperties

I have a properties file.

```
#My properties file
config1=first_config
config2=second_config
config3=third_config
config4=fourth_config
```

I have a class that loads the properties file in a small Java app. It works fine, specifically when I try to access each property within this class's method.

```
public class LoadProperties {
  public void loadProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties");
        prop.load(input);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling that class's method in another class, in a method.

```
public class MyClass {
  public void myMethod() {
    LoadProperties lp = new LoadProperties();
    lp.loadProperties();
    /*..More code...*/
  }
}
```

How do I access the properties in the `myMethod` method in the `MyClass` class?
I tried typing `prop.getProperty("[property_name]")`, which does not work.

Any ideas? I'm assuming that this would be how I would access the properties. I can store them in variables in the `loadProperties` class and return the variables, but I thought that I would be able to access them how I stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the LoadProperties class to load the properties and add a method to return the loaded properties.

```
public class LoadProperties {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    public LoadProperties() {
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("config.properties")){
            prop.load(fileInputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        LoadProperties loadProperties = new LoadProperties();
        System.out.println(loadProperties.getProperties().getProperty("config1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as for question code, you do not close the `FileInputStream`. You must close the stream when done with it, preferable using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: I know, I was being lazy and only answering the original question. Proper exception handling should also be implemented instead of using System.out.println